# Is it idiomatic to say "Pretend that I have a 10 year old son"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

In my another post (["Have you done a poo?" vs. "Did you poo?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239525/109190)) I said

> Pretend that I have a 10 year old son.

Is it idiomatic? Does that sound natural? Is it an appropriate beginning for discussion?

Comment: Note when an age is used as an adjective it gets hyphenated: "10-year-old son".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Pretend" means to *behave* in a way that makes something contrary to reality seem real. Children "pretend" when they are role-playing, and they act out imaginary situations.

If you are presenting a hypothetical scenario for someone to consider, it would be more idiomatic to say:

> *Imagine* that I have a 10-year-old son

OR

> *Let's say* that I have a 10-year-old son.

Comment: "Suppose" is another word that works here. I don't think "pretend" is totally incorrect, but these are more appropriate for sure. Native speakers also sometimes omit the "that".