# Is it idiomatic to say "He doesn't drink much water at school"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

In my another post (["Have you done a poo?" vs. "Did you poo?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239525/109190)) I said

> He doesn't drink much water at school.

Is it idiomatic? Does that sound natural? How about other possibilities?

> He doesn't remember to drink much water at school.
>
> He usually forget to drink much water at school.

Which one is clearer? Are there other expression appropriate here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All are OK, except that the third one should be *forgets* instead of *forget*.

You could also replace the word *much* with *enough*, to more directly say that he is drinking less than he should.